# Multiple Dialog Pop up on single click

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have the following code to generate dialog box . The flows goes like this

End of Test -> User Select to save or delete -> If user select delete another dialog box pop up to ask for delete confirmation.

The program works fine . However occasionally more than 1 delete dialog pop up. Did i make a mistake somewhere ?

Thanks.

```
private void buildEndTestDialog(){

    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle("End of Test");
    alert.setCancelable(false);


    alert.setNegativeButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Save
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            buildDeleteDialog();
        }
    });

    alert.show(); 
}

private void buildDeleteDialog() {

    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this result?");
    alert.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //delete result
        }
    });

    alert.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show(); 
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it is called twice , from your code snippet you have provided. Try catching the scenario where it is called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
    private void buildEndTestDialog(){
               ///rest of code
        alert.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                buildDeleteDialog();
            }
        });

        alert.show(); 
    }

    private void buildDeleteDialog() {

        ///rest of code

        alert.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                dialog.dismiss();
               buildEndTestDialog();
            }
        });

        alert.show(); 
    }
```

Comment: Hi geet , i need both the positive and negative buttons for other operation in the dialog .

Comment: Hi geet , is it necessary to have dialog.dismiss() as from what i see the dialog is dismiss once i clicked another of the 2 buttons . I will try it now.